# Reset google recaptcha in angular application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recaptcha

I'm using google's recaptcha in an angular project, it works as expected but I can't figure out how to reset it.

I have a form in which the user sends data and I would like after a successful post from the form to reset the form so that the user can send another mail.

In my controller I have the following method:

```
 var resetForm = function () {
   //reset my models
   //reset my flags

   //here I would like to reset the recaptcha

}
```

How can I do this from a function that is inside an angular controller ?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using version 1

```
Recaptcha.reload();
```

If you are using version 2

```
grecaptcha.reset();
```

Through selectors :

```
jQuery('#recaptcha_reload').click();
```

Comment: Is '#recaptcha_reload' generated by default, am Isue to have it ?

Comment: Yeah. The recaptcha script you are including generates this. So it will always work untill they change its id.

Comment: they must have changed it or I'm using an older version or something, as I can't seem to find it, jquerry returns an empty array.

Comment: Then just replace the id of the reload button in place of 'recaptcha_reload'.

Comment: Thanks a lot @brute_force ‍

Answer (score 5):

using `grecaptca` wont work in .ts, we need to read component instance using it's template reference **(#)** via @viewChild.

**Step 1:** Import

```
import {NgxCaptchaModule,ReCaptcha2Component} from 'ngx-captcha';
```

**Step 2:** Read template reference

```
@ViewChild('captchaElem') captchaElem: ReCaptcha2Component;
```

**Step 3:** Read component to reset/reload

```
this.captchaElem.resetCaptcha();
```

you can use a boolean like `isCaptcaSuccess` to use check if your captcha is valid. you can set the values inside handleExpire, handleSuccess events.

**Ngx captcha**

```
<ngx-recaptcha2 #captchaElem
   [siteKey]="siteKey"
   (reset)="handleReset()"
   (expire)="handleExpire()"
   (error)="handleError()"
   (load)="handleLoad()"
   (success)="handleSuccess($event)" >
</ngx-recaptcha2>
```

Comment: `this.captchaElem.resetCaptcha()` didn't work for me but `this.captchaElem.reloadCaptcha();`;

Answer (score 1):

Use `Recaptcha.reload();` to reload the captcha.

Comment: It gives me the error `Recaptcha is not defined`, what do I need to inject into the controller to get acess to recaptcha ?

Comment: have you included the script <script src=”https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha.js“></
script>

Comment: Yes I've included it, the recaptcha works on the site, but I can't seem to access it in the controller.

Comment: have you included the script file above the app.js file in the inclusion

Comment: Yes it's above all the angular related stuff so I'm not sure why can't I aces it.